# C# Unable to clear memory of large generic collection

Tags: c#, generics, collections, garbage-collection

i am putting 2 very large datasets into memory, performing a join to filter out a subset from the first collection and then attempting to destroy the second collection as it uses approximately 600MB of my system's RAM. The problem is that the code below is not working. After the code below runs, a foreach loop runs and takes about 15 mins. During this time the memory does NOT reduce from 600MB+. Am i doing something wrong?

```
List<APPLES> tmpApples = dataContext.Apples.ToList(); // 100MB
List<ORANGES> tmpOranges = dataContext.Oranges.ToList(); // 600MB

List<APPLES> filteredApples = tmpApples
    .Join(tmpOranges, apples => apples.Id, oranges => oranges.Id, (apples, oranges) => apples).ToList();
tmpOranges.Clear();
tmpOranges = null;
GC.Collect();
```

Note i re-use tmpApples later so i am not clearing it just now..

Comment: how large is filteredApples? Is it uesd afterwards somewhere?

Comment: both questions are answered above, approximately 100MB and yes it is used afterwards.

Comment: @Grant the question talks about tmpApples, not filteredApples ;)

Comment: Are you building for Release or Debug?

Comment: GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced);

Comment: sorry filteredapples is relatively small, a tiny fraction of the tmp dataset.

Comment: building for debug too..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few things to note:

- Unless your `dataContext` can be cleared / garbage collected, that may well be retaining references to a lot of objects
- Calling `Clear()` and then setting the variable to null is pointless, if you're really not doing anything else with the list. The GC can tell when you're not using a variable any more, in almost all cases.
- Presumably you're judging how much memory the process has reserved; I don't think the CLR will actually return memory to the operating system, but the memory which has been freed by garbage collection will be available to further uses *within* the CLR. (EDIT: As per comments below, it's possible that the CLR frees areas of the Large Object Heap, but I don't know for sure.)

Comment: @John as just mentioned in another comment i have created the lists outside of the using block for the data context. after the joins the context is disposed but this has made no difference. is there any way to get the memory back to the OS?

Comment: The CLR *does* return chunks, which were allocated for/as the large object heap only. Since neither the APPLES nor the ORANGES seem to be very large, you possible are (again) right here.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but a 600MB monster like tmpApples should be located on the large object heap. As far as I know the CLR GC will neither compact memory on the LOH nor give it back to the OS.

Comment: @Florian Greinacher it is not. The lists will consist out of many smaller objects, I assume. Those are allocated on the regular managed heap, as far as their individual sizes are not larger than the (mystical) limit for the LOH.

Comment: just read the mystical limit is 85,000 bytes - determined by performance tuning :)

Comment: @Grant. Unfortunately it is not sure to be that number. Mostly it is. But since exceptions exist (double array: 1000 elements) one cannot rely on it.

Comment: @user492238: Well, List<T> internally uses one array for storing its items. Now even if T is a reference type, it just needs enough items to let the array be big enough to be located on the LOH...

Comment: Please have a look at my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5470300/c-unable-to-clear-memory-of-large-generic-collection/5470732#5470732

Comment: i think i might just try to do all the joins and all the work inside SQL... agree?

Comment: This is probably the best solution :)

Answer (score 5):

Clearing, nullifying and collecting hardly ever has any (positive) effect. The GC will automatically detect when objects are not referenced anymore. Further more, As long as the `Join` operation runs, both the `tmpApples` and `tmpOranges` collections are referenced and with it all their objects. They can therefore not be collected.

A better solution would be to do the filter in the database:

```
// NOTE That I removed the ToList operations
IQueryable<APPLE> tmpApples = dataContext.Apples;
IQueryable<ORANGE> tmpOranges = dataContext.Oranges;

List<APPLES> filteredApples = tmpApples
    .Join(tmpOranges, apples => apples.Id, 
       oranges => oranges.Id, (apples, oranges) => apples)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: are you saying that even after the join has completed there is still a reference to the tmp collections??

Comment: The call to `Join()` also has a `ToList()` after it - so nothing else that we've been shown is referencing `tmpApples` and `tmpOranges` any more.

Comment: @Grant: After the join is completed (which happens after the call to `ToList` ends) the `tmpApples` is not referenced anymore (unless you are still using that of course). However, you are probably using LINQ to SQL. LINQ to SQL keeps all objects into memory. Therefore, it is much better to let this operation execute inside the database. Look at my example.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this data is not collected back is because although you are clearing the collection (hence collection does not have a reference to items anymore),**`DataContext` keeps a reference and this causes it to stay in memory.**

You have to dispose your `DataContext` as soon as you are done.

---

### UPDATE

OK, you probably have fallen victim to [large object issue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc534993.aspx).

Comment: @Aliostad i have just created the lists outside of the using block and then disposed of the datacontext after the joins. This has had no effect and memory continues to climb...

Comment: If so then there could be a **circular reference or you are binding them elsewhere.**

Comment: @Aliostad thanks.. ill have to do some reading about that then. in short though, anything i can do about it??

Comment: I cannot think of I am afraid.

Comment: @Aliostad Which "issue" regarding the LOH do you mean?

Comment: @Aliostad what does it has to do with eh LOH? Unlike regular menaged heap memory chunks, memory which was reserved as LOH *is* returnd to the OS after use.

Comment: See this http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/521147/large-object-heap-fragmentation-causes-outofmemoryexception

Comment: @Aliostad: This is unlikely an LOH issue. Only object bigger than 85k will be put in the LOH. Lists however, are build up by many small objects.  They live on the normal heap. The internal array (that contains the 32bit references) might be on the LOH, but this will hardly cause any problems.

Comment: @Aliostad there is no such thing as an "LOH issue". All cases I have seen so far, when serious defragmentation occoured on the LOH, were caused by misusing/misunderstanding by the editor: heavy allocation of large objects in a (way too) frequent manner. However, this does not seem to be the case here anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this as Large Object Heap issue you could try to not retrieve all apples at once but instead get them in "packets". So instead of calling

```
List<APPLE> apples = dataContext.Apples.ToList()
```

instead try to store the apples in separate lists

```
int packetSize = 100;
List<APPLE> applePacket1 = dataContext.Apples.Take(packetSize);
List<APPLE> applePacket2 = dataContext.Applies.Skip(packetSize).Take(packetSize);
```

Does that help?

Comment: I don't think this is a LOH issue. Only the `List<APPLE>` and `List<ORANGE>` instances will -possibly- be in the LOH, but the `APPLE` and `ORANGE` will almost certainly be in the normal heap. LOH will become a problem when you have many objects in the LOH. Most problems come from defragmentation of the LOH. We have currently no indication that the OP is creating many LOH objects.

Comment: @Steven +1 Dont know why so many answers here suddenly assume some strange "LOH" issue for such a common scenario

Answer (score 0):

Use some profiler tools or SOS.dll to find out, where your memory belongs to. If some operations take TOO much time, this sounds like you are swapping out to page file.

EDIT: Also keep in mind, the Debug version will delay the collection of local variables which are not referenced anymore for easier investigation.

Comment: @user tried release as well but has made no difference. thanks.

Comment: @Grant yes, like posted in other answers as well, I assume the memory is used up for the process and remains in the heap - unaccessible for other processes and waiting for the next huge list to be filled. Only profiling will bring clarity here.

Answer (score -1):

The only thing you're doing wrong is explicitly calling the Garbage collector. You don't need to do this (in fact you shouldn't) and as Steven says you don't need to do anything to the collections anyway they'll just go away - eventually.

If you're concern is the performance of the 15 minute foreach loop perhaps it is that loop which you should post. It is probably not related to the memory usage.

Comment: its not so much the performance of the loop, its the system resources that are being held from other process that need it.